# Ordering columns of string alphabetically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 columns of names that are several thousand rows long.
I need to arrange them in alphabetical order.
I attached a simplified image of the data (the sample table is on the left side of the image, and the ideal solution table is on the right side of the image)

Simplified image of the problem I am trying to solve.

[image: Simplified image of the problem I am trying to solve.]

Answer (score 1):

Using `SORT()` function should work. The `4th` parameter of the function states **[by_col]**, however the function needs to fill down for each row. That said, one can apply as :

[image]

---

```
=SORT(A1:C1,,,1)
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down, but if you are attempting to do for the whole range all at once, then you could try the following:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&BYROW(A1:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",,SORT(x,,1,1)))),"|",{1,2,3}),"|")
```

---

**Note:** Although the above formula works but it will work to a certain limit. As `TEXTJOIN()` function has a character limit, if the resulting string exceeds **32767 characters** (**cell limit**), then it returns the **#VALUE!** error.

---

Here is another alternative way:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, A1:C262144,
     δ, TOCOL(IF(α<>"",SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)))),
     φ, TOCOL(LEFT(α)),
     WRAPROWS(TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(TOCOL(α),δ,φ),{2,3},{1,1}),,1),3))
```

---

Tested with few 250K rows of data both the formulas seems to be working on my end, although it may differ based on data.

[image]

---